# Enviar mais de um parâmetro em requisição GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

Uso o código abaixo para enviar um parãmetro em uma requisição `Ajax` do tipo `GET`.

```
$('#cidades').load('cidades.php?estado=' + $('#estados').val());
```

Como faço para passar também um parâmetro chamado `recurso`?

Comment: Qual o nome da variável?

Comment: não entendi a dificuldade. Afinal, já está concatenando um parâmetro. Então basta seguir a lógica e concatenar outro... `+"&outro_parametro=valor"`

Comment: O nome da variável é: recurso

Comment: O que está de errado nesta concatenação?

`$('#transacao').load('transacao.php?estado='+$('#estados').val()+'&cliente='+idcl+'&teste='+idcl);`

Comment: Gladison, alguma resposta resolve o teu problema? É interessante você dar um feedback, pois outra pessoa pode ter o mesmo problema, e ao chegar aqui saberá o que foi feito. :) Veja [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) o que você pode fazer ao obter uma resposta para sua pergunta. ;)

Answer (score 10):

Outra maneira é enviando um objeto como "segundo parâmetro", segundo a [documentação do jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

```
var parametros = {
    estado: $('#estados').val(),
    recurso: $('#recurso').val()
};

$('#cidades').load('cidades.php', parametros, callback);

var callback = function() {
    //do something
}
```

Ainda é possível chamar uma função callback como terceiro parâmetro.

Comment: +1 Pelo "segundo argumento". É sempre melhor usar um recurso do jQuery no próprio jQuery do que concatenar (coisa que o jQuery faz internamente nesse caso)

Answer (score 5):

Se você continuar com essa concatenação aí no seu código, seria preferível utilizar a função `$.param` do jQuery.

```
var dados = {
   estado: $('#estados').val()
}

var  url = 'cidades.php?' + $.param(dados)
```

Mas de todas as formas considero melhor solução a resposta do @PedroJuniorCamara

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102853/4995

Comment: +1 pelo uso do $.param, Não conhecia essa função, é muito útil.

Comment: O jQuery usa ela internamente quando você usa o atributo `data` do ajax como objeto ;)

Answer (score 4):

Você só precisa separar as variáveis com o carácter **&**

```
$('#cidades').load('cidades.php?estado='+$('#estados').val()+'&recurso=seuRecurso');
```

---

Se você precisa usar mais parâmetros, acho muito melhor que faça do jeito que o Pedro e o Wallace disseram.

Comment: Concatenação é a coisa mais feia que existe na programação, né, @jbueno ?!?! +1

Comment: É? Não sei @WallaceMaxters

Comment: Olá, este seu script funcionou perfeitamente, mas para que eu consiga usar melhor estes recursos e implementar mais parametros, como faço para que a variavel IDCL utilizada no paramentro receba um conteúdo vindo de uma variável php? De uma olhada abaixo:

$('#cidades').load('cidades.php?estado='+$('#estados').val()+'&cliente='+idcl);

Comment: @jbueno eu não gosto de concatenar (pelo menos nas três linguagens que mais mexo, acho feio [python, php, javascript])

Comment: Se você precisa usar mais parâmetros, acho **muito** melhor que faça do jeito que o Pedro e o Wallace disseram. Quanto a tua outra dúvida, acho que é assunto pra outra pergunta, você pode perguntar quantas vezes precisar (desde que tenha bom senso, é claro).

Comment: concordo, plenamente. mas a minha dúvida agora está em como receber o valor de uma variável php e colocar dentro da variável IDCL. Pois mesmo utilizando o o jeito dos colegas acima, sempre vou precisar receber valor de variáveis de outra linguagem.

Comment: Gostar eu também não gosto @WallaceMaxters, mas isso não faz com que eu evite a todo o custo. Como parti do princípio que ele precisaria passar um ou dois parâmetros fiz dessa forma, mas como eu já disse, se começar a colocar mais já fica feio e tem formas **bem** melhores de fazer (como nas outras respostas).

Comment: Ai é outro problema @GladisonNeuzaPerosini. Se é outro problema, precisa de outra pergunta.

Comment: @jbueno eu entendi o que disse. Afinal, até para alguns tipos de retorno sou obrigado a concatenar, as vezes nas próprias bibliotecas que desenvolvo.

Comment: O que está de errado com esta concatenação?
$('#transacao').load('transacao.php?estado='+$('#estados').val()+'&cliente='+idcl+'&teste='+idcl);

Comment: Qual o problema com a resposta?

Answer (score 3):

Os parâmetros devem ser separador por um "&" desse modo:

```
link.php?param1=valor&param2=valor
```

No seu exemplo ficaria algo do tipo:

```
cidades.php?estado=valor&cidade=valor
```