# Problema de concatenação de string e variáveis na função load do jquery

Tags: javascript, variáveis, concatenação-de-string

**Segue o código completo JavaScript:**

```
var idcl = document.getElementById('idcl').value;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#estados').change(function(){
        $('#cidades').load('cidades.php?estado='+$('#estados').val()+'&cliente='+idcl);
        $('#transacao').load('transacao.php?estado='+$('#estados').val()+'&cliente='+idcl+'&teste='+$('#cidades').val());
    });
});
```

**Campos select:**

```
 <select name="cidades" id="cidades">...</select>
 <select name="transacao" id="transacao">...</select>
```

Não estou conseguindo fazer com que este parâmetro: `teste='+$('#cidades').val()` receba o valor que está em `#cidades`.

Comment: joga esse valor em uma variavel e dps concatena essa variavel.

Comment: com faço isso? me um exemplo, pois tenho pouco conhecimento em js

Comment: $('#estados') e $('#cidades') é um **<input>** ou um **<select>** ?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Enviar mais de um parâmetro em requisição GET](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102851/enviar-mais-de-um-par%c3%a2metro-em-requisi%c3%a7%c3%a3o-get)

Answer (score 2):

Tenta separar o valor em uma variavel.

```
var idcl = document.getElementById('idcl').value;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#estados').change(function(){
        var estados = $('#estados').val();
        $('#cidades').load('cidades.php?estado='+estados+'&cliente='+idcl);
        $('#transacao').load('transacao.php?estado='+ estados +'&cliente='+idcl+'&teste='+$('#cidades').val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Entendi mas como eu vou capturar os valores que estou em #estados e #cidades ?? Qual código utilizo?

Comment: alterei o codigo, da uma olhada, veja se concatenou o estado, faca o mesmo com cidade.

Answer (score 2):

Experimente fazer isso usando o método do jQuery mesmo, em baixo, eu criei um JSON para cada parâmetro:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#estados').change(function(){
       var params = {
            cliente:$('#idcl').val(),
            cidades:$('#cidades').val(),
            estado:$('#estados').val()
       };
        $('#cidades').load('cidades.php?estado=' + params.estado + '&cliente=' + params.cliente);
        $('#transacao').load('transacao.php?estado=' + params.estado + '&cliente=' + params.cliente + '&teste=' + params.cidades);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Para resgatar valores de `<select>` em jQuery, se faz assim:

```
var estado = $('#estados option:selected').attr('value');
```

Pois o objeto `<select>` não tem value, ele tem vários opções, e vc tem que trazer o valor da opção selecionada.

Answer (score 1):

Cara, o problema deve estar nos `option`'s seu `select`.

Verifique se você escreveu seu `select` como `<option value='ba'>Bahia</option>`. No caso que citei, se você utilizar `$('#estados').val()`, ele retornará `"ba"`.

Verifique também se o **id** está correto no `select`.

Às vezes é um problema de digitação que passa despercebido.