# Como passar mais um parâmetro e valor com outra variável via post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Preciso enviar para o arquivo **bairro.php** uma nova variável, usando *jQuery*, como faço?

Tenho um input do tipo *hidden* que contém a variável **idcl** que contém dado do cliente:

```
<input type="hidden" name="idcl" id="idcl" value="<?php echo $cliente; ?>" size="3">
```

Como passo esses dados para a rotina abaixo?

**Segue o código Java Script:**

```
   $.post("bairro.php",
             {cidade:$(this).val()},
                function(valor) {
                   $("select[name=bairro]").html(valor);
                   ...
```

Comment: Dentro do post?

Comment: sim, como faço?

Comment: Tem como montar esta estrutura modificada para passar uma variável? para eu ter como exemplo?

Comment: Qual variável você quer passar? De onde e como você captura ela? Sua pergunta está muito vaga, clique em [edit] e detalhe melhor seu problema.

Comment: ele ta fazendo post. não get o.O

Comment: Não acho que seja duplicata.

Comment: A lógica que você irá usar é a mesma que foi respondida na sua outra pergunta sobre esse mesmo assunto [Enviar mais de um parâmetro em requisição GET](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102851/enviar-mais-de-um-par%C3%A2metro-em-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-get#answer-102853). `GET` e `POST` tem praticamente o mesmo tratamento. Sugiro a leitura sobre o assunto, [veja esse artigo pra começar](http://www.webmaster.pt/requisicoes-ajax-jquery-2216.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta pegar pelo id, usando o `jquery`, como você já está fazendo:

```
  $.post("bairro.php",
              {cidade:$(this).val(), idcl: $("#idcl").val()},

              function(valor){
                 $("select[name=bairro]").html(valor);
```

Sugiro uma lida nestes links também:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp

Comment: vou fazer o teste, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

```
$.post( "test.php", { nome: "John", hora: "2pm" } );
```

ou em caso de envio de matriz.

```
$.post( "test.php", { 'nomes[]': [ "Jon", "Susan" ] } );
```

Adaptando sua rotina:

```
   $.post("bairro.php",
              {cidade:$(this).val(),idcl:$("#idcl").val()},

              function(valor){
                 $("select[name=bairro]").html(valor);
```

Não sei como está disposto as suas instancias, mas serve como base. abraços.

[fonte](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)